# check current password complexity on macOS

Tags: macos, passwords

Is there a way to check password complexity for an existing user account password in macOS?

I am trying to figure out if I setup a policy for my mac device to maintain a certain complexity for the password - say 1 non-alphanumeric, min 7 length etc, then I want to ensure that all user accounts on the Mac, if their existing password doesnt meet the password complexity defined, then they should change the password. But I am not sure how to check the password complexity conformation for existing passwords of the users.

PS: I am the administrator of the device.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that passwords are stored somewhere in plain text (or symmetrically encrypted, which is just as bad), which is unlikely. Password complexity should only be possible to verify at creation time. If you want to enforce it *post factum*, reset all users' passwords and make them choose new ones.

Comment: Actually I was hoping that like in iOS we can enforce a stricter passcode, we can do so in macOS also for password. But I guess, your suggestion is valid - I can enforce password resets for all the users on the device.